# MySql value and sum(value) in same row without group

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I want to get the current row quantity with COUNT(*) and the total row quantity over all rows as column in every row (needed for a report trying to avoid scripting it outside the sql).
I can't use SUM(qty) because i don't want to group my result by reasons and when i use a parameter with := i only get the total qty in the last row.

My current Query looks something like

```
SET @sumTotal:=0;
SELECT reason, qty, (@sumTotal := @sumTotal + qty) AS total_qty
FROM
(
 SELECT reason, COUNT(*) AS qty 
 FROM someTable
 --Imagine a huge amount of joins here
 GROUP BY someTableId 
)base
```

The table someTable looks like

```
----------------------
projectid | reason  
----------------------
1         | reason11 
1         | reason12 
2         | reason21
2         | reason22 
2         | reason23   
3         | reason31  
.
.
. 
3         | reason35   
----------------------
```

The result should look something like

```
----------------------------
reason  | qty | totalqty
----------------------------
reason1 | 2   | 10
reason2 | 3   | 10
reason3 | 5   | 10
----------------------------
```

Am i maybe thinking in the wrong direction and there is a easy way to fix this?

Comment: nobody can help you if you dont share some example data with the result you need

Comment: @RaymondNijland - added the expected result, thx for the hint

Comment: You should also post the source table or tabels with example data

Comment: This should not be necessary since qty results from count(*) and totalqty is the sum from qty over all rows - adding sample data to a row count seems overkill to me

Comment: If it seems overkill to provide example data then you are on your own i geuss.. example data gives much more understanding to the question

Comment: im not sure if the given example data is what you expected but i appreciate that you're not giving up hope on me and still try to teach me the best way to ask my question - thx

Comment: Do you grouping rows by `projectid` or `reason` column?

Comment: @Alexander i group by project id - reason column may have different entries so that group would not work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use auxiliary SELECT query to count the number of `someTable` rows.

```
SELECT reason, qty, total_qty
FROM
    (
    SELECT reason, COUNT(*) AS qty 
    FROM someTable
    GROUP BY someTableId 
    ), 
    (
    SELECT count(*)  AS total_qty
    FROM someTable
    )
```

This produces a Cartesian product between the derived tables of subqueries. Second subquery will consist of single row with total quantity. Thus, the total quantity will be added to the first subquery.

Comment: Actually i wanted to avoid using the FROM term two times and i hoped there is an easier way to do this. since the research didnt bring up anything else i guess this is the only way to do it. For bigger queries using a temp table could make it a bit clearer. Thx for help.